# bash scripting: looping and file manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a directory with some images in it. Some of these have the same name. How can I rename the duplicates without losing the original? I would like it to loop through the directory, checking for images with the same names and rename one of them. I am using Linux BASH

```
for i in $ImagesToCopy
do
cd $2                #change to dest directory
if [ ! -e $i ]       #if file is not in destination
then 
cd $1                #then change to source where images are
cp $i $2             #and copy image to destination
fi
done 

cd $2
for i in $ImagesToCopy    #for images in the source directory
do 
cd $2                     #change to destination directory
if [ -f $i ]              #if the file is there
then cd $1                #then change to source directory
cp $i $2/$i.JPG           #and copy the image but append it with.jpg
fi
done
```

Comment: In one directory, there cannot be two files with the same name.  Please clarify what you are asking.  It is helpful to give examples.  Also, you'll get much better answers if you show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: I have a folder of images. Some of these images are in sub-directories with the same name as other images in other directories. For all images, I want to copy them to a new directory, and if there are any duplicate filenames, I want to append .JPG on the end of the existing filename.

EDIT: code updated

Comment: You could just use `cp --backup=numbered src dst`

Comment: How many times will you ask the same question?

Comment: if you could read you would see that it isn't the same question, it is just in the same context, but wanting to do different things. Thanks for your input though, great to see your solid knowledge has really come to the rescue.